# TronGrid losses information in raw_data

Tags: tron

Today (18 March, 2024), we receive more errors: missed `timestamp` in response of trongrid.

Previously, all works fine, we success get `timestamp` from `raw_data` in response from `/wallet/gettransactionbyid`.

Request example:

```
curl --location 'https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactionbyid' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "value": "4f4c906b2d1a2e0f3d09e1360b4ee0c1f5abe6a462b494c6b8242f9d6c079584"
}'
```

Response:

```json
{
    "ret": [
        {
            "contractRet": "SUCCESS"
        }
    ],
    "signature": [
        "fc0c47f61942e321175cb37f6cf73549cb8bc918403ff7557f298c948fb0ba97f786342a8d9f66285adced4583604c5f446c54ce6c97b298a0a9f0deeb9bd1ef01"
    ],
    "txID": "4f4c906b2d1a2e0f3d09e1360b4ee0c1f5abe6a462b494c6b8242f9d6c079584",
    "raw_data": {
        "contract": [
            {
                "parameter": {
                    "value": {
                        "amount": 1,
                        "owner_address": "41f0927876c8a1a8129d0e7ce3bdd4fd252ddfe9f3",
                        "to_address": "419d8ffb0e30c13552d1ede1e78d2bae603c75351c"
                    },
                    "type_url": "type.googleapis.com/protocol.TransferContract"
                },
                "type": "TransferContract"
            }
        ],
        "ref_block_bytes": "b867",
        "ref_block_hash": "8bf9929b20577d9d",
        "expiration": 1710678969000
    },
    "raw_data_hex": "0a02b86722088bf9929b20577d9d40a895a6e3e4315a65080112610a2d747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e5472616e73666572436f6e747261637412300a1541f0927876c8a1a8129d0e7ce3bdd4fd252ddfe9f31215419d8ffb0e30c13552d1ede1e78d2bae603c75351c1801"
}
```

And in this response - `timestamp` missed in `raw_data`, but transaction was successfull.

I try to check other transactions, and see interesting case - some have it, some don't.

Maybe trongrid change protocol? How I can receive timestamp for transactions?

Thank.